# Java Swing: Modal loading screen?

Tags: swing

I have a Java swing application which loads a web page. Sometimes, the web page takes a while to load depending on the user's internet connection.

I want to block this frame until page has loaded.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The simplest option is to pop up a modal dialog:

```
JDialog modalDialog = new JDialog(frame, "Busy", ModalityType.DOCUMENT_MODAL);
modalDialog.setSize(200, 150);
modalDialog.setLocationRelativeTo(frame);
modalDialog.setVisible(true);
```

You may want to put a progress bar in it.

Answer (score 0):

It is possible...
I figured out a solution.

I had that problem too.

When you create your modal dialog, as proposed by [another answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4873282/3982001), only the user can close it.
It is only useful if you can make it dispose itself when the loading ends.

[UPDATE]

Here is my Dialog Class

```
public final class Loading extends javax.swing.JDialog {

    /*
     * Creates new form Loading
     * @param parent
     * @param modal
     */
    public Loading(java.awt.Frame parent,boolean modal) {
        super(parent, modal);
        initComponents();
    }

    private void formWindowActivated(java.awt.event.WindowEvent evt) {                                     
        //Code to execute while loading
        this.dispose();
    }                                                       
}
```

And here you call it like this.

```
Loading l = new Loading(this/*In case you class is a frame, null otherwise*/, true);
l.setVisible(true);
```

And after executing the loading code it dismisses and continues the code on the parent class.

Comment: You can provide to the loading task a callback to invoke the dispose method on your dialog.